# Leaderboard style query in GORM for a Groovy/Grails app

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails app in production where we will be implementing a leaderboard. Let's say that the users are playing rock-paper-scissors and the leaderboard is tallying wins, losses and ties. That's fine, no problem. But now our user base has become large enough that a person would have to scroll and scroll and scroll to find where they are in the list.  What we'd like to do is show the top 10 or so in the leader board (this is being displayed on an iPhone btw) and then the user's name with their rank against everyone else like this:

1. Andrew
2. Bruce
3. Charlie
4. Doug
5. ...

3,194 YOU

I know this can be achieved by doing a query for the complete list and then calculating the position but that seems expensive to perform every time. One alternative I thought about was just running that query from a quartz job and saving everyone's current position in the leaderboard so it's easily accessible. I'm not in love with that either because then it's not going to be a real time answer.

I think what I'm looking for is a GORM way to almost do an indexOf for a single record among its peers based on the query criteria.

Comment: why not calculate the high score table as an overnight batch job (like StackOverflow does)

Comment: Right, as I mentioned I am considering doing this with Quartz and sacrificing the true real-time aspect of the query. Cheers Tim, thanks for weighing in.

Comment: you might use standard caching technique like varnish so itd calculated one time, or do some caching yourself, just interval-like save and update the computed list and in the mvc just pass the list from db